# Set permissions for folder using nsfilemanager

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I create application for Mac OS and have some question.
How I can change permissions for folder using NSFileManager or maybe another way?

with finder it's easy, but I need do this programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that – as long as you have enough privileges – with the method

[`- (BOOL)setAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSFileAttributeKey,id> *)attributes ofItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413667-setattributes)

These keys are relevant

- `NSFileOwnerAccountName` sets the owner
- `NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName` sets the group
- `NSFilePosixPermissions` the numeric permissions

Comment: thank you for your answer!
where I can get list of NSFilePosixPermissions?

Comment: and how I can get more privileges?

Comment: That's a numeric value of the standard UNIX permissions like 644, 755. More privileges is an advanced topic. You need a helper tool and if you want to distribute your app in the App Store you can't.

Comment: it is interesting, thanks!